# Animating the BrowserWindow across the Desktop using Greensocks GSAP

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, desktop-application, gsap

I'm using Electron to create a desktop app and so far my code works but I'm having a problem integrating Greensock's GSAP to it, I'm trying to animate the application to a certain (x,y) position on the screen immediately it loads.

All imports function correctly but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, here's my code in its simplest form.

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const gsap = require('gsap');
const Easing = gsap.Easing;


function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({width: 300,height: 400});  // create the browser window
  win.loadFile('mainpage.html');
  win.webContents.openDevTools();
  
  gsap.to(win, {x:700, y:20, duration: 1});  //now animate to this position on screen 
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);
```

The problem is the application loads, but it doesn't move, everything works except the gsap action. What am I doing wrong, or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Hi! from what i know, you can use gsap to animate elements inside the window,  you sure you can animate the window itself?

Comment: @Anatsu i'm aware also, but how, can you help me out. thanks.

Comment: If you can't affect it with JavaScript then you can't affect it with GSAP. I am not aware of any functionality that allows you to animate browser windows themselves.

Comment: Don't think anyone can help you mate, The Electron framework is bound to the rules of javascript.